# 02 Ford Escape valve ticks on first start in the morning

Tags: valve, escape

It's only on the first start. If I leave it running after the first start it will take for a while. Possibly forever I'm not sure. What I've been doing is turning it off after a second or two and then turning it back on. That second time I start it the valve ticking is not there.

It's only coming from one of the valves.

It's had an oil leak for a while. So I don't know if the previous owner had put stop leak in it but I did. Before the last oil change though I put a can of seafoam in and let it run for about 400 miles. There's currently no oil additives in it except a half a quart of Marvel's mystery oil. The last time I change the oil, which was a few days ago, there was no debris at all in the oil, it was silky smooth.

Another potential cause of the problem is the engine used to search up to 4000 RPMs when you first start it. I cleaned out the idle air control and it's not perfect but it's a lot better now.

The part that sucks about this is I can only test it out once a day. After that second start it'll run all day long.

What do you think the problem is? Could this just be a faulty hydraulic lifter?

Comment: Sounds like a worn lifter(s) are bleeding down when engine is off, this is not normal, lifters should be replaced with New ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you have to remove the heads to replace the lash adjuster on a 2002 Ford Escape?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/74084/do-you-have-to-remove-the-heads-to-replace-the-lash-adjuster-on-a-2002-ford-esca)

Comment: So basically covered in your other question.

Comment: Moab, alright thanks that's the route I'm going. I still haven't got them replaced yet though.

Comment: Solar Mike, they aren't the same question. Can you please explain how you think they're the same question.

Comment: @user875234 The question that Solar Mike is referring to is also about valve/lifter tick in an '02 Ford Escape. May not be the same thing, but it is definitely relevant. I'd check it out just because you may get another perspective. I know it's not *exactly* the same, but related. :)

Comment: @kyle_engineer but they are not the same question. One reason I know this is because they are both my questions (although just reading them would suffice). They are different questions about different things so they are not the same thing.