# Do you have to remove the heads to replace the lash adjuster on a 2002 Ford Escape?

Tags: valve, escape

Hello I guess I'm replacing a lash adjuster today. Before I start I'd like to get a better idea of what I'm getting myself into. I know that you're supposed to replace all of them at once and that you have to pair them with the cams if you want to do the job properly but I'm just trying to get a lifter tick to go away.

Is the job going to be just open up the valve cover and pull out the damaged lash adjuster and replace it with a new one? Or is this going to be something a lot more complicated?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What engine? 4 or 6 cylinder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a V6 engine No you do not, If the 4 cylinder uses the same type of cam-follower arrangement it is basically the same procedure as outlined here for the V6. The tool for the follower may be different also.

Remove valve covers

Remove spark plugs

Remove rh front wheel

Remove splash shield in wheel well to expose the crankshaft pulley and center bolt

.
[image]
.

Rotate engine using a socket on the crankshaft bolt until camshaft lobe is pointing away from follower, do this for each follower as they are removed.

use a spring compressor to compress spring to remove follower, once this is done use pliers to remove lifter/lash adjuster.

.
[image]

.
[image]

I have removed this type of follower on various cars without special tools but recommend using one if you are not a professional.

[image]

.

Comment: How do you do it without special tools? I'm not a professional but I'm feeling lucky.

Comment: using a 12oz hammer you gently knock the follower out, usually from the spring side towards the lifter, but not always, depends on the design of the follower. I would have to see an actual engine to know for sure. Putting them back in with a new lifter is easier because the lifter will not be pumped up with oil and will compress easily allowing insertion much easier.

Comment: You don't soak the lifters prior to insertion? (I really don't know on these, which is why I'm asking. Normal to soak lifters so they are not dry on startup for most pushrod engines, but I'm sure you know that.)

Comment: I never soak them, been doing this for 50 years.

Comment: On second thought I think I'll run a spring compressor. I tried seeing how I might tap the following route but couldn't come up with a good way of doing it without potentially breaking something.  ...do you know if you have to adjust the valve clearance after replacing a lash adjuster?

Comment: Most are non adjustable, plug and play.

Comment: I rented a spring compressor but it doesn't fit. So I guess I'm back to feeling lucky. Can you explain more about how you hit it with a hammer please. I don't see a way to do that. I've attached some pictures. https://imgur.com/a/x4JguAV

Comment: From the spring side hit the end of the follower straight towards the lifter, use a brass punch if needed, it should pop out with some force, do not hit the spring inadvertently. If that does not work, try the other direction.

Comment: This is the correct one, best price I can find>>>>>>>https://www.autotoolworld.com/OTC-303-473-Valve-Spring-Compressor-T94P-6565-BH_p_161290.html

Comment: And then to get the follower back in can you just press it in with your hands or do you have to use a vise grip or something somehow? .. because the spring will be fully decompressed at that point, right?

Comment: opposite method to reinstall but should be easier with new lifter installed.

Comment: I ended up giving up and putting everything back together. Maybe if I had you here to show me how to do it I'd go for it but I don't see any good coming for me hitting things with a hammer down there. I'd for sure mess it up but now I can at least drive it for a little bit longer until that lifter becomes a constant problem. I guess I'll try taking it apart again once I can find a cheap version of that tool.